# How to redirect old website to a new one, but access the assets from the old site with .htaccess?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I hava a old site, example.com. What i need to do is redirect it to new website example.com.np. But the new website points to files of the old website, example.com. Is there a way I can redirect example.com to example.com.np, but access the assets from the old website?
My .htaccess for example.com is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: you can redirect from your host provider

Comment: Are asset requests somehow recognisable and distinguishable from the requests you want to redirect? Eg all under a common directory like `assets/` or something?  You'll need to be able to write a rule which recognises whether the request should be redirected, or not, eg based on directory.  Is `index.php` the only request that should be redirected?

Comment: yes, just the index.php..and I don't know much about writing .htaccess rule

Comment: Thank you, I've done it through cloudflare page rules options.